# Google Maps add a placecard

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed

Is it possible to add a place card on Google maps like in this example: http://www.haydensinrye.co.uk/Haydens/Find_Us.html?

I couldn't find a reference to this in the [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/)n.

I'm using [this method](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) to embed my map (under "Code Examples").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site you linked to uses [Google Maps Embed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#overview).
There is no way to get the same in the Google Maps API JS v3 automatically

For embed, an example on how to use it is:

```
   <iframe
      width="600"
      height="450"
      frameborder="0" style="border:0"
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
        &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

Comment: how to do it? Im confused

Comment: You simply add it to your pages HTML. Why are you confused?

Answer (score 2):

If you want something like the sample site you should just style your info window and open it automatically (without having to click the marker).
You can add directions opt. like that. If you want a save option add **signed_in=true** after your API key.

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Note that the **signed_in option is deprecated** and will not work in future versions.
All of it can be found in the API documentation (it's huge I know).

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a long time too but I found this example:

https://codepen.io/jonathanphz/pen/Wxorqj

```
//HTML
<div class="map-container">
    <div class="placeDiv">
        <div class="placecard__container">

          <div class="placecard__left">
            <p class="placecard__business-name">China Bistro Name Goes Here</p>
            <p class="placecard__info">9 Avenida Ramón Luis Rivera, Bayamón, 00961, Puerto Rico</p>
            <a class="placecard__view-large" target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=18.416035,-66.162618&amp;z=18&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=AR&amp;mapclient=embed&amp;cid=2947398168469204860" id="A_41">View larger map</a>
          </div> <!-- placecard__left -->

          <div class="placecard__right">
              <a class="placecard__direction-link" target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=18.416035,-66.162618&amp;z=18&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=AR&amp;mapclient=embed&amp;daddr=Roberto%20Perez%20Obregon%20Law%20Office%209%20Avenida%20Ram%C3%B3n%20Luis%20Rivera%20Bayam%C3%B3n%2C%2000961%20Puerto%20Rico@18.4160349,-66.1626177"
              id="A_9">
                  <div class="placecard__direction-icon"></div>
                  Directions
              </a>
          </div> <!-- placecard__right -->

        </div> <!-- placecard__container -->
    </div> <!-- placeDiv -->
</div> <!-- map-container -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>


//css
#map-canvas{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.placeDiv {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
}

.map-container {
  position: relative;
}

.placecard {

  &__container {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px;
    max-width: 330px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    font: normal normal normal normal 11px / normal Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 9px 4px 9px 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  &__left {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
  }

  &__right {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }

  &__business-name {
    cursor: default;
    height: 19px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;
    perspective-origin: 100px 9.5px;
    transform-origin: 100px 9.5px;
    font: normal normal 500 normal 14px / normal Roboto, Arial;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
  }

  &__info {
    color: rgb(91, 91, 91);
    cursor: default;
    height: 32px;
    width: 200px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(91, 91, 91);
    perspective-origin: 100px 16px;
    transform-origin: 100px 16px;
    border: 0px none rgb(91, 91, 91);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px / normal Roboto, Arial;
    margin: 6px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(91, 91, 91) none 0px;
  }

  &__direction-icon {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/embed/images/entity11.png") repeat scroll 0px 0px / 70px 210px padding-box border-box;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  &__direction-link {
    color: rgb(58, 132, 223);
    display: block;
    height: 43px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 54.7344px;
  }

  &__view-large {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: rgb(58, 132, 223);
    text-decoration: none;
  }

}


//js
// if HTML DOM Element that contains the map is found...
if (document.getElementById('map-canvas')) {

  // Coordinates to center the map
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.41604, -66.1626177);

  // Other options for the map, pretty much selfexplanatory
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    query: 'Roberto Perez Obregon Law Office',
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  // Attach a map to the DOM Element, with the defined settings
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: "Roberto Perez Obregon Law Office",
  });


  //Resize map
  google.map.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  google.map.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.map.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);
  });

}
```